# how to send contents of a textbox in vb6 to a notepad document

Tags: vb6

I am trying to send the data inserted into a textbox into a notepad document so that the data can be held for future reference, as i am trying to create an assessment date reminder as i am a student.

But whenever i try to send the data with this code by writing data = "txtAssign_Name, txtAssign_Due" when i check the notepad after running the program, all that is in the document is txtAssign_Name, txtAssign_Due.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim Data As String

txtAssign_Name.Text = ""

txtAssign_Due.Text = ""

Data = ""

Open "F:\Personal\date calender test - Copy\test.txt" For Output As #1

    Print #1, Data

Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: All the above code would be expected to save is "" , as that is all that is in data.

Comment: @David McElhaney
that didn't seem to help, after entering the code you gave it either input a , or nothing at all into the notepad

Comment: @CMaster
ok well could you give some advice on how to rectify the code so it will do the function that i want it to do?

Comment: @CMaster the data will be re-read back into vb as it is supposed to keep specified dates recorded then each time it is opened these can be individually selected to see time till that date

Comment: Comments about answers should go on the answer, not on the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Data = txtAssign_Name.Text & ", " & txtAssign_Due.Text
```

(In the lines above, you will want to NOT set those values to "")

Answer (score 0):

Note - using the built in VB6 writing to text files will result in your output being formated in a way so that VB6 can read it back in again. So all strings will have quotes aroud them, other values are displayed in a variety of odd ways, commas seperate all values.

If the output text file is desired to be primarily for human use, then I find using the richtextbox control a better way of creating the file. Add it from Project -> Components -> Controls -> Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0

Add the Rich text box to your form (you can set visible = false if you don't want users to see it). Add your data to it something like this:

```
RichTextBox1.text = txtAssingn_Name.text & ", " & txt_Assing_Due.text
' If you need to add more things, add them on to the end like this
RichTextBox1.text = richtextbox1.text & vbcrlf & "More text on the next line"
```

Then, when all the data is added, you just do this

```
RichTextBox1.SaveFile "C:\Test.txt", rtfText
```

rtfText is a visual basic constant, that tells the RTB to save as plain text. The alterntaive is rtfRTF. You can learn more about the RTB on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261653%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so a comment above states that you want to be able to read the data back into VB.

The code as it shown in the question will just output a blank text file, as the variable Data is set to "", so that is all that will be output.

What you need is something like this

```
private Sub SaveData()
    dim SaveFile as integer

    SaveFile = Freefile ' This gets a file number not currently in use
    Open "F:\Personal\date calender test - Copy\test.txt" For Output As #Savefile
    write #SaveFile, txtAssign_Name.Text, txtAssign_Due.Text
    close #savefile
end sub
```

And call `SaveData` in the appropriate place. NOT form load, as the user won't have entered anything at this point. Either after the user has pressed a button, or on Form_Unload if you want it to autosave on form close.

To populate your form again, something like this

```
private sub LoadData()
    dim LoadFile as integer
    dim StringData as string

    loadfile = freefile
    Open "F:\Personal\date calender test - Copy\test.txt" For Input As #loadfile
    input #loadfile, StringData
    txtAssign_Name.Text = StringData
    input #loadfile, StringData
    txtAssign_Name.Text = stringdata
    close #loadfile

end sub
```

You should also add error handing whenever working with files. VB6 is quite particular and its very easy to throw an exception when dealing with files.

Comment: i adjusted my code too acommadate the code you gave me and i am now getting 'Run-time error '52': bad file name or number

Comment: On which line? The error seems reasonably self explanatory.

Comment: the error is indicated to be on the Open "F:\Personal\date calender test - Copy\test.txt" For Output As #Savefile part of the program unsure if it will go to the load sequence as well

Comment: In the load routine I gave you, there was initally a bad variable name. That is now fixed.

Does the folder ""F:\Personal\date calender test - Copy\" already exist? If not, that will cause errors.

Comment: yes the folder already exists that is where the program is located

Comment: If the folder exists and the file is not already open, that seems odd. What is the value of Savefile in this case? Does the line `Savefile = freefile` immediatley preceed the open line? (Freefile is a visual basic variable that provides the latest free file number)

Comment: it is working now after moving a few things around but it is not putting the data where i want it to go, it is putting it back into the input textboxes instead of the listbox above them

Comment: Ah, well that's easy enough to fix. Instead of setting the text boxes to the read back data, replace those lines with `ListBoxName.additem stringdata`

Comment: that has worked getting the data into the table but now it has also cause another problem as i want to be able to click on the name inside the listbox and have it display the date that it is due and the days until it is due in a label to the side of it

Comment: That's another question, outside of the scope for this one. (The question is about how to save/load information in text boxes). If you are having difficulty putting data in and out of controls though, I think you need to read some basic tutorials on Visual Basic.

Comment: it's not that i don't know the commands for the function i am just unsure as to how to implement it here

Comment: Well, write up a new question explaining clearly: what it is you want to do, what you have tried so far, and what happens when you run the code you have tried but doesn't work.